# get_name can only be called from the main thread error

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I got this problem in unity :

> get_name can only be called from the main thread.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeDc9.png)

Comment: Are you calling that function from another Thread? Shows us where you are calling that function from

Comment: Post any code or error messages as text in your question. Don't post pictures of code.

Comment: Thats a pretty picture ya got there, mind sharing with us where that code is located?  Or how it is being called?

Comment: thanks , i know why i get this wrong .

Comment: client.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(filePath);
            Debug.Log("下载完成");

            //读取XML文件
            ReadXMLFile(filePath);
        };

Comment: `DownloadFileCompleted` is being called from another Thread but the duplicate shows a fix for the **"can only be called from the main thread."** error